# Translations for my plugin don't show up

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, localization

I'm pulling my hair out with this one:

I want to provide translations for my plugin, but they're not showing up. I followed the documentation and took the following steps:

1. Set up local wordpress using docker
2. Added Text Domain to Plugin-Info `* Text Domain: my-plugin`
3. Added Domain Path to Plugin-Info  `* Domain Path: /languages/`
4. Added translation loading to `plugin.php`:

```
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'load_i18n' );
function load_i18n() {
  load_plugin_textdomain("my-plugin", false, dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages/');
}
```

5. I have a `settings.php` which is responsible for rendering my plugin's Settings page and is initialized from `plugin.php`. I added this line there to test my translation: `<?php _e( 'Hello, dear user!', 'my-plugin' ); ?>`
6. I used `wp i18n make-pot` to create the pot file. It successfully detects the line in settings and the plugin info stuff and creates what looks like a proper `my-plugin.pot` inside my plugin's `language` directory.
7. I used PoEdit to create translations from that pot file. I made `en_US.po` and `en_US.mo` inside the `language` directory. I translated my test string in the settings page as well as the plugin description.
8. Set Wordpress language to en_US via general settings. (I also tried `define ('WPLANG', 'en_US');` inside `wp_config.php`)
9. Installed my plugin.

Translations don't show up (original text is displayed), neither in the plugin description nor the settings page.
I also tried other hooks for loading the text domain and other languages. The plugin is not going to be uploaded to the plugin repository, so the translations need to come with the plugin directly.

Answer (score 1):

So i found my own mistake:

I did not properly read https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/internationalization/localization/#translate-the-po-file

My `.mo` files were just called like `en-US.mo`. But they should be called `my-plugin-en-US.mo`.

Solved!